# How to make an alias last forever?

Tags: bash, command-line, alias, nano

I want to make an alias python="python3". I do this by using
nano ~/.bash_profile and then typing: alias python="python3" , and save. Then I write: source ~/.bash_profile to overwrite changes. But this alias only lasts for the terminal session that i am in. When i start a new terminal session I have to write source ~/.bash_profile for the alias python="python3" in order for it to go into effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have in your ~/.bashrc file a command like

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

?

If not, you have to add it

Anyway, it's common practice to create ~/.bash_aliases to use aliases and then source it in ~/.bashrc like:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Comment: Hi!

When I did ls -a in my home directory there was no .bashrc file there. So I did nano ~/.bashrc and in then wrote . ~/.bash_profile. But it still won't load the alias. I am quite new to the command line so what does the first part of the expression -f after the if statement mean? I understand ~/.bash_aliases refers to the file .bash_aliases in the home directory but what does '-f' mean? Is it necessary to have brackets around the expression after the if statement? What would happen if you didn't have brackets around the expression?

Comment: If it still doesn't load alias, you need to tell more info about how you're logging in shell and what your files are containing

Comment: Also I think it would be useful for you to know how shell files are loaded in different environments:
https://zwischenzugs.files.wordpress.com/2018/01/shell-startup-actual.png

Comment: *-f some_file* means than *if some_file is a regular file type*. Not directory, socket or any other, just regular file.
Read about it here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

Comment: And the brackets - it's a *test* command. But for convenience it's bade as square brackets and you can even find it in */usr/bin/[*. And test plays test role) Read about test here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins

Answer (score 0):

`~/.bash_profile` is only sourced by interactive **login** shells, as the bash manpage will tell you.  If you want to have it available also in interactive **non-login** shells, I suggest that you place the alias definitions into a separate file (say: `~/.bash_interactive`) and source this file from both `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`.

Answer (score -1):

To make aliases permanent, you've to set them in a file that’s read when you launch the terminal. i.e. try adding your line `alias python=python3` into `~/.bashrc` or into `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` for remote logins. If you want the command being executed for all users, put it into `/etc/bash.bashrc`. In general, aliases can be kept in the `~/.bash_aliases` file and that file is loaded by `~/.bashrc`. Remember to uncomment the following lines in `~/.bashrc` to enable the use of `~/.bash_aliases` if you're running on older versions of Ubuntu. On Ubuntu 11.04 and later, it's already enabled:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

The aliased command will be available on any new terminal. To have the aliased command on any existing terminal one need to source `~/.bashrc` from that terminal as

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: It's not good practice to touch system-wide `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: @SarathKumarSivan : From what do you conclude that a `/etc/bash.bashrc` would have an effect? This file is not mentioned in the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: @user1934428 When bash initializes a non-login interactive bash shell on a Debian/Ubuntu-like system, the shell first reads /etc/bash.bashrc and then reads ~/.bashrc. The reason that /etc/bash.bashrc does not appear in normal bash documentation is that it is a feature added by Debian and adopted by Ubuntu. You can check out the Debian explanation here: https://sources.debian.org/src/bash/4.1-3+deb6u2/debian/README/#L50-L56.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It's a bit creepy if such features depend on the way bash is compiled. But we don't know whether the OP is using Debian or Ubuntu, so I think you should at least put it into your answer, that bash **may** process this file, if it is configured to do so. I wonder whether, for a given bash, we can easily find out (without much experimentation) with what flags it has been compiled....